# Toggle background for a button programmitacly in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, toggle

```
class Split_recycler_adapter (var arrayList: ArrayList<Split_recycler_model>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Split_recycler_adapter.Viewholder>()  {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Viewholder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.changesplit_recycler_item,parent,false)
        return Viewholder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Viewholder, position: Int) {
        val split_modal = arrayList[position]
        var checked = true

        Log.e("position_outside_loop->","$position")

        holder.split_text.text = split_modal.getText()
        holder.split_text.setOnClickListener{
                    if(checked){
                        Log.e("check->","Working")
                        holder.split_text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_button_gradient)
                        holder.split_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454546"))
                        checked = false
                    }else{
                        holder.split_text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dropdown_gradient)
                        holder.split_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A4A4A4"))
                        checked = true
                    }


        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }
    class Viewholder(Itemview: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(Itemview) {

        val split_text : TextView = Itemview.findViewById(R.id.split_text)

    }

}
```

This code helps me to change the background of the button when clicked and revert the background when one more click is done but this is not the exact thing i want ,  I need to toggle the background on click, when one click is done it should want to remove the background of the other button , only one button should be highlighted at a time , Please help me if any one know the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way.

You have added a click listener in a binder and performed `checked` logic for that item mainly situated at that holder position. It won't affect other items at other positions. So to update other positions' state, you have to manage the state for each item by adding `isChecked` variable in `Split_recycler_model` class.

```
    class Split_recycler_model {
        var isChecked : Boolean = false
    }
```

And in onClick of view, update your list item for that particular adapterPosition.

Updated click action,

```
holder.split_text.setOnClickListener{
    checkItem(adapterPosition)
}
```

```
fun checkItem(adapterPosition:Int) {
  arrayList.forEachIndexed{index,item ->
      item.apply{
        isChecked = (index == adapterPosition)
      }
  }

  /**
      Here you can manually calculate the changes
      to update adapter to improve performance. 
      For now, I'm updating it with the `notifyDataSetChanged` method.
  */
  notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it clearly